# history.length & history.GoBack() JS

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, browser-history

i invoked some javascript into my webbrowser.
the aim was to get the history.length, and if the length == 0, exit the app on backkey pressed.

so i used window.external.notify(history.length +'');

in browser_Scriptnotify: int16 navicounter = Convert.ToInt16(e.value);

the problem is, the history.length value is growing with each goBack(), i thought it would be shrinking ..

anybody got a solution for me? i need an indicator if i'm at the first page of the history or not.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into window.on('statechange',...) and window.on('popstate',...)

or you can use progressive enhancement of browser-storage(BS), along with cookies.
-User lands on site. Create cookie/BS with value of 0
-User lands on a new page and cookie is set.
-Get the value of the cookie
-Add 1 to value of cookie/BS
-Re-Set the cookie with the new value

-JS needs cookie
-Fetch cookie value
-Process JS

-User leaves site.
-Remove cookie/BS

Comment: thanks, could you explain a bit more, how it works and how to use it?

Comment: i just need a int value, that tells me how far i'm away from the startpage.

Comment: Ohh... well that's different. How are you calulating how far from the start page you are? The number of links followed after they land on your site? or the hierarchy of where you are related to the main landing page?

Comment: at first, it's a wp7 app, so at first i was counting the times the browser_Navigating event was fired.
now, i thought javascript would count it in the history, so i could use the history.length, but it's always count upwards, even if i goBack .. :/

Comment: this cookie/BS (for what stands bs?) is new to me, how can i tell a cookie to grow/shrink and so on?

Comment: BS standas for Browser-Storage, and is outlined IN my answer. I will edit though to make more clear, and add to cookies thing.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. would be nice, but i will have to edit the cookie/bs in every navigating-process, or is the browser doing that automaticly?

Comment: If you're really really that interested in the browsers navigation process you're not going to get a full answer to what ever it is you're trying to accomplish though here until you have questions about HTML5 Storage, Browsers History API, and the history polyfill for all browsers HistoryJS. Once you have a grasp of those three things (at least their concepts) try to use that to solve your problem, then come back and ask questions about why those specifics may not be doing what you want because what you're trying to do sounds simple in theory, but is actually pretty complex

Comment: well, i think the normal counter is the better solution here, but thanks :)

Comment: Let me know if you get something to work that way, it's be interesting to see what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

cause it always counts up, you can see if it's 0. If it is, you're at the first page. If you want to go to the first page

```
window.history.go(-window.history.length);
```

should do it.

Comment: i don't want to go to the first page, i just want to know how far i am away from it (a int value) 
;)

Comment: that would be -window.history.length then, wouldn't it ?

Comment: nope, because when i navigate back(history.GoBack()), the distance would shrink, but not the history.length.

Comment: I see what you meen; I was looking at it the same way as the guy that designed window.history...going back adds to the history; it may be the same page...it's still history.